# OSM Relation IDs for boundaries

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries

Is there a way to get *only* the relation IDs of a boundary in OSM?
E.g. relation #350303 http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/350303 is Pärnu maakond in Estonia which is an admin_level=6 boundary.

So my question is: How do I get the relation IDs of every admin_level=X boundary in country XY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with the Overpass API:

```
area[admin_level=2]["name"="Eesti"]->.boundaryarea;
rel(area.boundaryarea)["admin_level"];
out;
```